# How do I deactivate deep code analysis?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, code-analysis

I think that by mistake I have enabled the "deep code analysis". How do I disable it?

Comment: I'm not sure, what you mean with 'deep' but generally `Project -> Properties -> Code Analysis`

Comment: It seems you have resharper installed. There is no "deep" code analysis

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose you selected a more strict rule set in the Analyze + Configure dialog.  The default is "Microsoft Mininum Recommended Rules".